# How can I turn off animations in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: unity

I'm having a problem with LibreOffice and Ubuntu 13.10.  Namely, whenever I try to access different Calc spreadsheets by ctrl-clicking the Calc icon on the left toolbar, the system becomes completely unusable for several seconds while some animation of the windows rearranging themselves plays.  I would like to either:

1. disable that animation entirely (apparently not allowed once Unity2D became merged with Unity)
2. be able to alt-tab between windows rather than between applications

Honestly, I have no desire to have a fancy 'lickable' interface; I don't want to use a Mac.  How can I turn all of these helpful 'features' (ie, time-wasting animations) off?

Comment: Try cycling through the windows of the same application with alt-` - back tick is usually above the Tab key, or use another desktop environment.

Answer (score 6):

Install Unity Tweak Tool:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Run Unity Tweak Tool and open the "General" settings under "Window Manager"

[image]

Then under "Animations" disable "Window Animations".

[image]

You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (Alt + tilde) to switch between open windows of the same application.

Answer (score 3):

I found this thread because the animations were too slow. I'm running Ubuntu on a virtualbox. Just in case this might help someone else, enabling 3D acceleration on my virtualbox settings made the animations smooth, and I didn't need to disable them anymore.